# Rails 3 routing question: sub-resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have 2 models: User and Interest.

To get a specific users interest, you can visit this URL:

```
/users/1/interests
```

Now to my problem. Each User can have several children, which is references to other users. Now I want to get a specific child, by doing this:

```
/users/1/children/1/interests
```

But I'm not sure how to set this up in the routes.rb. Both URL's should call the show action in the interests_controller, where I just want to check like this:

```
def show
  @user = User.find params[:id]
  if params[:child_id]
    @user = @user.children.find_by_id params[:child_id]
  end
  @interests = @user.interests
end
```

So I want to use the same interests_controller for both URL's, but I'm not sure how to write that in my routes.rb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best possible resource you need to do nesting like this: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources

In your case, it might look something like this:

```
map.resources :users do |users|
  users.resources :children do |children|
    children.resources :interests
  end
end
```

But, like he mentions in the article, I would also recommend against this. There is no real benefit to this type of URL versus a simple `/children/[id]/interests` and good use of the session, and it is much easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks, super helpful answer. I know that it's best not to have many nested resources, but in some cases you have to do it, and my project kind of dictates it.

Comment: Understandable, I've had a few of those projects too. :) Thankfully, Rails still supports it!